# Exclude saturday and sunday from shipping time estimates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Im using a shipping time estimate plugin - [[Sky Verge Woocommerce Shipping Estimates]](https://www.skyverge.com/product/woocommerce-shipping-estimates/)

And it works really well showing shipping estimates per shipping zone at checkout, but it does not exclude weekends, therefore shipping estimates are not quite right.

Is there anyway to remove saturday and sunday from the estimates?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`SkyVerge\WooCommerce\ShippingEstimates::generate_delivery_estimate_days` contains two filters that you can use to extend the from and to dates based on the current day.

The two filters are `wc_shipping_estimate_days_from` and `wc_shipping_estimate_days_to`.

```php
add_filter( 'wc_shipping_estimate_days_from', '_extend_by_weekends' );
add_filter( 'wc_shipping_estimate_days_to', '_extend_by_weekends' );

function _extend_by_weekends( $days ) {
  $count = 0;
  $next = time(); // start from today

  while ( $days ) {
    if ( ( int )date( 'N', $next ) < 6 ) { // it's a workday!
        $days--; // decrement as a workday
    }
    $count++; // count a day
    $next += DAY_IN_SECONDS;
  }
  return $count;
}
```

Something like the above will work. Of course it doesn't take into account holidays, for example, but if you have a holiday calendar you can extend it to tack on (skip day decrement) on further conditions.

Hope this helps get you started.